# Excel Toolbar buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I have added some new "button" to the Excel 2007 toolbar

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
        <tab id="customTab" label="ClaroTech">
            <group id="customGroup" label="Animalcare Group">

<button id="customButton1" label="Custom Button1" imageMso="SmartArtChangeColorsGallery" size="large" onAction="Callback1" />
<button id="customButton2" label="Custom Button2" imageMso="SmartArtChangeColorsGallery" size="large" onAction="Callback2" />
            </group>
        </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
```

This works fine and the toolbar displays. I have added the following code to one of the sheets Modules

```
Sub Callback2()
 MsgBox "Welcome"
End Sub
```

When the button is pressed then I get the following error[image]

I have no idea what is causing this error, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a valid button callback signature. It should be:

```
Sub Callback2(control As IRibbonControl)
 MsgBox "Welcome"
End Sub
```

If you use the CustomUI editor, it can generate the callback stubs for you.